# Selecting odd and even elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to style `odd` and `even` `tr` elements differently from my table.

Here is my code:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/online_lorno/d161c57c/)

```js
/*
Create a one-liner code to add the class ‘odd’ to an odd number row and the class ‘even’ to an even number row
Hint: Use the nth-child selector and the end() function
*/
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
tr.odd {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
}
tr.even {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>odd</td>
    <td>odd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>even</td>
    <td>even</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>odd</td>
    <td>odd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>even</td>
    <td>even</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>odd</td>
    <td>odd</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hint: Use the nth-child selector and the end() function

Comment: $( "tr:even" ).addClass('even');$( "tr:odd" ).addClass('odd'); see https://api.jquery.com/even-selector/

Answer (score 3):

If you have jQuery, you can use [`:odd`](https://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) and [`:even`](https://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) selectors

```
$('tr:odd').addClass('odd');
$('tr:even').addClass('even');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/d161c57c/49/)

```js
$('tr:odd').addClass('odd');
$('tr:even').addClass('even');
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
tr.odd {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
}
tr.even {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>odd</td>
    <td>odd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>even</td>
    <td>even</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>odd</td>
    <td>odd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>even</td>
    <td>even</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>odd</td>
    <td>odd</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Using CSS only**

You can also select odd and even element using CSS `nth-child` selector.

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
}
tr:nth-child(2n + 1) {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>odd</td>
    <td>odd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>even</td>
    <td>even</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>odd</td>
    <td>odd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>even</td>
    <td>even</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>odd</td>
    <td>odd</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `css` `:nth-of-type()` pseudo-class selector set with `odd` , `even` values

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
}
tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>odd</td>
    <td>odd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>even</td>
    <td>even</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>odd</td>
    <td>odd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>even</td>
    <td>even</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>odd</td>
    <td>odd</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the CSS odd/even selectors.

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add styles using pseudo-class selector :nth-of-type with even and odd.

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
}
tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>odd</td>
    <td>odd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>even</td>
    <td>even</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>odd</td>
    <td>odd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>even</td>
    <td>even</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>odd</td>
    <td>odd</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```